# SSRS 2005 rename report issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm having small issue with SSRS2005. 
In my project I have 2 reports (lets say ReportA and ReportB). 
Recently, I  renamed ReportA to ReportC and now  I have 3 links on server (ReportA,ReportB,ReportC).
Ofcourse ReportA is the same link as ReportC. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: What is your goal?  Do you want to eliminate extra links?  Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Yeah I have 2 reports in my solution and I want to eliminate extra one on page.

Comment: @Chris, care to up vote or accept my answer below please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managing reports in SSRS2005 should be for development purposes and deployment of reports. However to really manage the reports as "files" (ie: rename, delete, etc), you should be using the server pages themselves.

```
http://<your server>/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
```

In there you'll be able do proper deleting and renaming of reports, and you won't have to copy, rename, copy back like you tried above.